# Url references in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, urls

I am using TexMaker. I would like to know how to include web site references in the .bib file. I am using bibliography style , alpha. How does the website reference appear in the bibliography

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your `.bib` file contains `url` fields: Use the `alphaurl` style instead of `alpha`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {www.tex.stackexchange.com},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{alphaurl}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Answer (score 0):

IMVHO the "right" way to cite a webpage (until the Powers That Be add a proper bibliography entry type, that is ;-) is to use the @Misc type, and place the URL in howpublished.