# LaTeX: Show return symbol at url line break

Tags: urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Option to break urls with carriage-return symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28835/option-to-break-urls-with-carriage-return-symbol)

I wonder if there is a possibility to show symbol (for example return symbol U+23CE or latex `\hookleftarrow`) at line break in `\url` command. I mean

```
\url{http://example.com/very-long-url-here-for-example/long/and/long/page.html}
```

should produce something like this:

```
http://example.com/very-long-url-here-for-example/ \hookrightarrow
long/and/long/page.html
```

I compile with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.