# How to emulate \url hyphenating without using the url package?

Tags: hyphenation, urls

I'm forced to avoid the `url` package in a proceedings paper (!) but my bibliography includes a long URL. I already

```
\newcommand{\url}[1]{{\tttext{#1}}}
```

but the URL spills over to the margin as it isn't hyphenated. I would rather not change the bibliography manually to add the hyphens (my current solution) but rather define the new `\url` command to put in the `\-` commands before dots and forward slashes. I've seen a few related questions but close enough for my TeX skills...

Also, is there a way to make the hyphenation happen without an actual hyphen?

EDIT: sorry, I should have said, that not only the `url` package is disallowed...but I cannot include any extra package. the packages that are included are

```
graphicx multicol footmisc amsmath amsfonts
```

So I guess this is a plainTeX question.

Comment: Maybe this question helps: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44361/how-to-automatically-hyphenate-within-texttt)

Comment: @PeterGrill: no extra packages, see my edit.

Comment: @cgnieder: interesting. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without any package, your only hope is that they use a fairly recent TeX distribution:

```
\newcommand{\url}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \catcode`/=\active\catcode`.=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
```

This will allow breaks after periods and slashes.

If you have some special character in your URLs, they can be taken care of, just present some examples.

Comment: I noticed the following `\raggedright` behavior with both your answer as well as the `url` package;  Namely, while breaks are "allowed" after slashes, it will frequently *prefer* to move the whole url down to the next line, in preference to breaking at a slash (if the whole url fits on a single line).  Is that expected behavior?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, with `\raggedright` hyphenation is essentially suppressed. Use `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e`. A different strategy might be using `{/\penalty0 }` in the definition instead of `{/\discretionary{}{}{}}`

Answer (score 7):

You can adapt the solution from [Option to break urls with carriage-return symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28835/option-to-break-urls-with-carriage-return-symbol/28863#28863) to define `\url`:

[image]

---

If you prefer the use a dash at the end of the line then replace the line `\discretionary{-}{}{}` which yields:

[image]

but note that this can be confusing as it is difficult to tell if the trailing dash is part of the URL or not.  This is not an issue if the link is to be clicked on with online viewing, but for printed version this may be an issue.

---

Alternatively, if you use `\discretionary{\usebox\MyArrowBox}{}{}` then you can have a special character (I used `\hookleftarrow`, but you can adapt this to use any other symbol) at the end of the line to indicate the continued text so that there is no confusion with a dash.

[image]

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newsavebox\MyArrowBox%
\sbox\MyArrowBox{$\hookleftarrow$}%
\makeatletter%
\newcommand*{\BreakableChar}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \prw@zbreak%
  \discretionary{}{}{}%
  %\discretionary{-}{}{}% If want a dash
  %\discretionary{\usebox\MyArrowBox}{}{}%
  \prw@zbreak%
}%

\newcounter{index}%
\newcommand{\url}[1]{%
  \StrLen{#1 }[\stringLength]%
  \forloop[1]{index}{1}{\value{index}<\stringLength}{%
    \StrChar{#1}{\value{index}}[\currentLetter]%
    {\currentLetter\BreakableChar}%
  }%
}%

\newcommand*{\MyUrl}{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50777/how-to-emulate-url-hyphenating-without-using-the-url-package}%

\begin{document}
\parbox{4cm}{\url{\MyUrl}}

\bigskip
\parbox{7cm}{\url{\MyUrl}}
\end{document}
```