# Misc in plainnat appearance

Tags: line-breaking, natbib

I use `plainnat` to cite online material as follows:

```
@misc{Group2009,
  author = {Miniwatts Marketing},
  title = {{Internet World Stats}},
  howpublished = "\url{http://www.internetworldstats.com/stats.htm}",
    year = {2013},
    note = "[Online; accessed 19-July-2013]"
 }
```

but it gives a lot of space between the words, as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image: output]!

How do I fix this?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50777/how-to-emulate-url-hyphenating-without-using-the-url-package Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115690/urls-in-bibliography-latex-not-breaking-line-as-expected

Comment: Not directly related to your query, but of relevance: Since the entry has a so-called "corporate" author, you should write `author = {{Miniwatts Marketing}}` (note the second pair of curly braces) rather than just `author = {Miniwatts Marketing}``. This will ensure that (i) author-year type citations will be to `Miniwatts Marketing` instead of `Marketing`, (ii) the entry in the references list will be sorted under `Mi...` instead of `Ma...`, and (iii) (depending on the bibliography style in use) the entry's author won't be typeset as "Marketing, Miniwatts" or, worse yet, "Marketing, M.".

Answer (score 0):

[image: see]

```
@misc{Group2009,
  author = {Miniwatts Marketing},
  title = {Internet World Stats},
  howpublished = {Online},
  url= {http://www.internetworldstats.com/stats.htm},
    year = {2013},
    note = {[Accessed 19-July-2013]}
 }
```

Comment: You should have double curly braces around the contents of the `author` and `title` fields, as you're dealing with a "corporate" author and so as to avoid lowercasing the words "World" and "Stats".