# Avoiding line breaks for file extensions

Tags: line-breaking

I have made a system to list a lot of LaTeX files, and I wanted to include the path to all the files, in order to be able to quickly copy-paste it. These paths can get quite long, and fiddling around with some settings gave me the following setup that works well for most paths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\noindent\path{C:/Folder/Subfolder/Subsubfolder/EvenMoreSubfoldernames/filename.tex}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

This will give nice line breaks for most of my files. In this specific example (and also for some actual files I have), the line breaks only at the file extension, so we would get

```
C:/Folder/Subfolder/Subsubfolder/EvenMoreSubfoldernames/filename
.tex
```

as output. Is it possible to avoid line breaks at the file extensions? There should be no dots elsewhere in the path, so avoiding line breaks at dots would also work. I originally used [Steven B. Segletes' answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219497/70156) with `\texttt`, but this does not combine with the `sloppypar` environment, and hence usually goes into the margin before breaking.

In summary:

**Is it possible to avoid line breaks at the extension of a file path, using `\url` or `\texttt`?**

Comment: Note that `\texttt` is just a font command -- your solution wil be independent of this.  I think the reason it's used in the linked answer is just to match the style of the `\url` macro.

Comment: [This  answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10419/28808) may point you to the right direction in the docs for `url`, as it discusses the definition of which characters can allow breaking -- though I don't see `.` in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just suppress in the `textttt` answer the possibility to have linebreak on `.`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`[\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{[\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  %\begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\discretionary{}{}{}}%
%  \catcode`/=\active\catcode`[=\active\catcode`.=\active
  \catcode`/=\active\catcode`[=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\noindent\texttt{C:/Folder/Subfolder/Subsubfolder/EvenMoreSubfoldernames/filename.tex}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative approach, tweaking the behaviour of `\url`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\@\do\\\do\/\do\!\do\_\do\|\do\;\do\>\do\]%
 \do\)\do\,\do\?\do\&\do\'\do+\do\=\do\#}%
\begin{document}
\begin{sloppypar}
\noindent\path{C:/Folder/Subfolder/Subsubfolder/EvenMoreSubfoldernames/filename.tex}
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

The line starting `\def\UrlBreaks` (in fact split over 2 lines) is lifted from `url.sty`, with `\do\.` removed.  What it does here is redefine the list of characters at which urls can be broken to exclude full stops.