# How can I allow line-breaks before a double-colon (::) in \texttt?

Tags: line-breaking, typewriter

I use `\texttt` to markup code. Sometimes I get lines like this which overflow the page since Latex doesn't line-break in `\texttt`

> deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. The `std::ostream::traits_type::eq` function ...

I think I want to allow line breaks to happen before a `::` in one of these, so line-braking the above to this would be acceptable:

> deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. The `std::ostream`
>
> `::traits_type::eq` function ...

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219445/line-break-in-texttt) approaches what I want -- it allows line-breaking *after* a given *single* character -- but I can't see how to adapt it.

How do I write something which will line-break *before* a `:` in `\texttt` but only before the *first* `:` in a `::`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can massage the string a bit:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cppstring}{m}
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_spraff_cppstring_tl { #1 }
  % change _ to a printable underscore
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { _ } { \cO\_ } \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
  % change :: to \linebreak[0]::
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { :: } { \c{linebreak}[0]:: } \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
  % print the result
  \texttt{ \tl_use:N \l_spraff_cppstring_tl }
 }
\tl_new:N \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\noindent % just for the example
unrecoverable error occurs during the transformation, then a
\cppstring{std::ostream::traits_type::eq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This can be improved, for example, by doing `\linebreak[0]` only after the first `::`. The simplest way is adding a further replacement

```
% remove the first \linebreak[0]
\regex_replace_once:nnN { \c{linebreak}\[0\] } {} \l_spraff_cppstring_tl
```

before printing the result.

Note that, differently from the strategy of making characters active, the command `\cppstring` can also go in the argument to other commands.

This has the advantage of also working with `babel-french` where colons are treated specially.

---

This does not do magic. The example with the text

```
lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum

\noindent % just for the example
unrecoverable error occurs during the transformation, then a
\cppstring{stdxxxxx::ostreamxxxxxx::traits_typexxxxx::eqxxxxxxx} lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum
```

will not justify the paragraph, because the first opportunity at `::` cannot be taken as it would create too wide spaces in the line.

In an emergency, when rewriting is impossible or unsuccessfull, you can use `sloppypar`:

```
lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum

\begin{sloppypar}
\noindent % just for the example
unrecoverable error occurs during the transformation, then a
\cppstring{stdxxxxx::ostreamxxxxxx::traits_typexxxxx::eqxxxxxxx} lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum 
\end{sloppypar}
```

[image]

Comment: This [doesn't quite work](http://pastebin.com/Jgez162f), it will break lines before the  :: but it adds line breaks too late to prevent the box from overflowing. http://imgur.com/a/UKlcs

Comment: @spraff It's not magic: that paragraph simply cannot be split reasonably. Splitting before `::ostreamxxxxxx` would stretch too much the spaces in the line. Unless you allow hyphenation or reformulate your text, you're doomed. It's a completely different problem.

Comment: @spraff If you enclose the offending paragraph in the `sloppypar` environment, you get awful word spacing, but the break is taken at the first `::`. Leave these adjustments for the final revision stage.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the accepted answer at the cited question, I here, in addition, make `:` active and test to see if the next character is a `:`.  If so, I `\allowbreak`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\let\svcolon:
\catcode`:=\active %
\makeatletter
\def:{\@ifnextchar:{\allowbreak\svcolon}{\svcolon}}
\makeatother
\catcode`:=12 %
\renewcommand\texttt{\catcode`:=\active \texttthelp}
\newcommand{\texttthelp}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`[\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{[\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \catcode`/=\active\catcode`[=\active\catcode`.=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4]

unrecoverable error occurs during the transformation, then a
\texttt{std::ostream::traits\_type::eq}

coverable error occurs during the transformation, then a
\texttt{std::ostream::traits\_type::eq}
\end{document}
```

[image]