# texttt is not breaking the line at existing hyphens

Tags: formatting, hyphenation

I've got longer phrases separated with hyphens that I'd like to typeset in typewriter font. I'd like latex to break the lines to avoid them from overflowing:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

    Normal font breaks the line:

    a-very-long-text-in-typewriter-font-separated-by-hyphens-that-should-break-the-line.

    But typewriter font does not:

    \texttt{a-very-long-text-in-typewriter-font-separated-by-hyphens-that-should-break-the-line.}
\end{document}
```

Just to be clear, I don't want latex to add more hyphens, I just want it to break the line at the existing ones.

Comment: See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412253/linebreak-in-texttt-works-with-textttt-in-mathmode) for potential answers (in addition to the proposed one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\raggedright
    Normal font breaks the line:

    a-very-long-text-in-typewriter-font-separated-by-hyphens-that-should-break-the-line.

    But typewriter font does not:

    \texttt{%
     \hyphenchar\font=`\- % enable hyphenation
     \hyphenpenalty=10000 % disable it again
     \exhyphenpenalty=-50 % enable (encourage) it at explicit hyphens
     a-very-long-text-in-typewriter-font-separated-by-hyphens-that-should-break-the-line.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, but it seems to also affect any \texttt{} that come afterwards. Is there a way to limit it to one \texttt{} ?

Comment: @Stefan oh sorry you need to set `\hyphenchar\font=-1 ` at the end of the text (inside the group, just before the `}` (it's a global setting)

Comment: That does the trick! Do I have to reset the other two as well?

Comment: @Stefan no they are local so will be reset at the `}`