# Enable highlighting and auto-line-breaking for texttt{}

Tags: highlighting, typewriter, soul

I'm using the following command to modify `texttt{}` so that it automatically breaks long lines (without inserting a hyphen), and it's very helpful when writing documents where I have to write lengthy URLS, command-line examples, etc.

```
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`[\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{[\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \catcode`/=\active\catcode`[=\active\catcode`.=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
```

I can't seem to enable highlighting for `texttt{}` via `soul` or the `hl{}` commands with this functionality. How do I enable both this line-breaking functionality and highlighting?

I've attempted this via:

```
\usepackage{soul}
...
  \scantokens{\hl{#1}\noexpand}%
```

However, this causes the text to be truncated mid-sentence.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Since the question clearly references the answer at this question: [Line break in texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219445/line-break-in-texttt), I'll take a stab.

For whatever reason, the use of `\hl` inside of the revised `\texttt` causes truncation by the amount of special/active characters (`/`, `[`, `.`) inside the string.  The only solution is to pad the input string by that number of extra tokens, so that `\hl` eats up the desired string, while leaving the padding behind.

While I did not *yet* find a way to do this on-the-fly inside of the `\texttt`, I did figure out how to do it if alerted before entering `\texttt`.  Thus, the macro `\HLtt{}` is used to highlight the complete `\texttt` string (rather than just a piece of it).

It works (before invoking `\textt`) by passing the argument to `listofitems` to count the special characters.  Then it adds one `x` to `\tmp` for each occurrence of a special character.  Finally it invokes `\textt` with the original argument *plus* the padding.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar[?]{/||[||.}% SET THE CHARS TO SEARCH FOR
\newcommand\HLtt[1]{%
  \readlist\tmplist{#1}% FIND THE SEARCHED FOR CHARS (CALL IT n)
  \def\tmp{}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\tmplist[]{% CREATE A STRING OF n-1 TOKENS
    \ifnum\xcnt=1\relax\else%
      \expandafter\def\expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\tmp x}\fi}%
  \def\tmpA{#1}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\texttt%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\hl%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\tmpA\tmp}}%
}


\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`[\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{[\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \catcode`/=\active\catcode`[=\active\catcode`.=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
\usepackage{soul,xcolor}
\begin{document}
If an unrecoverable error occurs during the transformation, then a
\texttt{javax.xml.transform.TransformerException} is thrown.

If an unrecoverable error occurs during the transformation, then a
\HLtt{\$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt\_address']['feInterface']['fe\_admin\_fieldList']}

\HLtt{\$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt\_address']['feInterface']}

\HLtt{\$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt\_address']}

\HLtt{\$GLOBALS['TCA']}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found the solution from your linked question some time back, but couldn't find the original post via Google. Thank you for taking the time to answer this.

Comment: @DevNull I see my answer is not universal.  The number of added tokens (`x` in my MWE) should equal the total number of `/`, `[` and `.` encountered.

Comment: In some cases, this works, but in other cases, it appends a `xxxx` literal to the text. Longer strings render find, but a short string (i.e. `\HLtt{PUT}`) renders as `PUTxxxx`.

Comment: Typo above: longer strings render fine, but short strings have `xxxx` appended to them.

Comment: @DevNull See my 2nd comment.  The right number of filler to add depends on how many instances of the special characters appear.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Does this mean I would need to calculate the number of `/` `[` and `.` characters in the string and use different functions for different strings (i.e. is there a "one-size fits all" solution)?

Comment: @DevNull Yes...and I am thinking on a possible solution.

Comment: @DevNull Please see my revision.

Comment: I'll have to figure out how to install `listofitems.sty` on the headless server I'm using. I'll let you know how it goes once I get that dependency installed.