# Extra space after custom texttt

Tags: spacing, typewriter

I am currently using the below codes for auto line breaking in Latex. However, below code places an extra space behind the /texttt. How can I remove the extra space being placed after the /texttt command? The spacing looks like the below image.

[image: How it looks like..]

Code:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\aepath[1]{%%
  \bgroup
    \ttfamily
    \ae@path#1\relax\@nil
  \egroup}
\def\ae@path#1#2\@nil{%%
  \def\ae@continue{}%%
  \detokenize{#1}\unskip\penalty\z@  
  \ifx\relax#2
  \else 
    \def\ae@continue{\ae@path#2\@nil}%%
  \fi
  \ae@continue}
\makeatother

\let\texttt\aepath
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably a `%` after `\ifx\relax#2` will do.

Comment: The code you used (from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219454/4427) had an unprotected end-of-line. I fixed it.

Comment: @egreg Impressive! (how fast you found it, I mean.)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I searched `aepath`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you! Your suggestion works!