# Combining Wrapping \texttt{} with Sections and TOC - Improper alphabetic constant

Tags: line-breaking, typewriter

Was working on getting line wrapping working for code, and came across a solution which was working for me - until I tried to add a table of contents to my code. The issue seems to be with using the new \texttt{} inside a (sub)section heading. Lots of errors, and the TOC is broken (on Overleaf, for the MWE) - in my actual project, it won't even compile because of the same errors.

I'm using Steven Segletes solution to line-wrapping on specific characters in \texttt{} from here: [Line break in texttt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219445/line-break-in-texttt?rq=1)

The error stack starts with "Improper alphabetic constant." twice, then goes on to "Missing $ inserted.", "Missing } inserted.", "Missing $ inserted.", and so on.

I'm writing in markdown and compiling with pandoc to tex, so I would really rather not have to have two versions of \texttt (i.e. make a \textttwrap or \textttnowrap or similar).

My MWE (it's using scrarticle, because that's what I'm using, but the issue is the same with article).

```
\documentclass{scrarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\catcode`_=12 %
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`[\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{[\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{_\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`:\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{:\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \catcode`/=\active\catcode`[=\active\catcode`.=\active\catcode`_=\active\catcode`:=\active
  \scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
\catcode`_=8 %

\title{subsection-texttt-mwe}
\author{c.angustaylor }
\date{January 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\texttt{this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_this_is_long_but_wraps_properly_}

\subsection{\texttt{this_is_tt_subsection}}

Doesn't work with no escapes for \_, which is fine in texttt{} with the solution otherwise.

% \subsection{\texttt{this\_is\_tt\_subsection}}

% Also doesn't work with escapes for \_

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protect the `\texttt`

```
\subsection{\protect\texttt{this_is_tt_subsection}}
```

Or make the definition generally robust with

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttt}[1]{%
```

or with (this requires a new LaTeX, in older LaTeX  add `\usepackage{xparse}`):

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\texttt}{m}{%
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much - `\DeclareRobustCommand` works perfectly.From doing some digging, seems like that's preferred for data that will be written into aux files and read back, so in this case, the TOC.