# Space missing in list of tables after monospaced / typewriter text

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, typewriter

I am using this custom version of the `\texttt` command from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428393/293047) to enable line breaks in monospaced / typewriter text in my document:

```latex
\newcommand*\justify{%
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-% allowing hyphenation
}
% Allow linebreaks inside \texttt on '_' (also removes the need to escape underscores).
% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219497/293047
\catcode`_=12 %
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{_\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{-\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \catcode`/=\active
  \catcode`_=\active
  \catcode`.=\active
  \catcode`-=\active
  \justify\scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
\catcode`_=8 %
```

I have multiple instances where I use `\texttt` in the `\caption` of a table.
This works fine in the main text right below the table, but in my list of tables, the space after the monospaced text is missing:

[image: Screenshot from the MWE]

**What do I need to do to ensure the space is rendered?**

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcommand*\justify{%
  \fontdimen2\font=0.4em% interword space
  \fontdimen3\font=0.2em% interword stretch
  \fontdimen4\font=0.1em% interword shrink
  \fontdimen7\font=0.1em% extra space
  \hyphenchar\font=`\-% allowing hyphenation
}
% Allow linebreaks inside \texttt on '_' (also removes the need to escape underscores).
% Taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219497/293047
\catcode`_=12 %
\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \ttfamily
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`/\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{/\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`_\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{_\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`.\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{.\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`-\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{-\discretionary{}{}{}}%
  \catcode`/=\active
  \catcode`_=\active
  \catcode`.=\active
  \catcode`-=\active
  \justify\scantokens{#1\noexpand}%
  \endgroup
}
\catcode`_=8 %

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        {} &                                  Category\_Name \\
        0  &                                 Category 1 \\
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The \texttt{Category\_Name} text feature}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try replacing `\renewcommand{\texttt}[1]{%` with `\RenewDocumentCommand\texttt{m}{%`, or put `\protect` before `\texttt` inside the caption.

Comment: @UdiFogiel thank you, the first option has fixed the problem.

Comment: for compatibility with older LaTeX you can still use old-fashioned `\DeclareRobustCommand{\texttt}{...}`