# Lines with texttt reach into the page border, how to prevent?

Tags: line-breaking, margins, boxes, typewriter

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,inner=2.4cm,outer=2cm,top=1.78cm,bottom=1.5cm,twoside,headheight=1.1cm,headsep=0.9cm,foot=1.2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\RequirePackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

Falls Sie von einer VerA.web-Version, die die Konfigurationsdateien
noch nicht in \texttt{/etc/veraweb} ablegt, aktualisieren, müssen Sie
dort zunächst (nur) die gegenüber den in der \texttt{veraweb.war}
ausgelieferten Dateien angepaßten Konfigurationen aus dem Verzeichnis
\texttt{/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/veraweb/OCTOPUS/config\_*.xml}
Ihrer alten Installation hinkopieren.

\end{document}
```

(Note, these aren’t the actual page margins we use; I tweaked it to exhibit the issue with the standard font as well.)

This renders as:

[image: rendering of MWE]

How can I tell pdflatex (which we run twice already anyway) to *always* prevent such runoffs, at the cost of slightly worse spacing of the surrounding lines (intra-word, or possibly hanging lines) automatically?

To be clear: I know I could shuffle the text in the paragraph around a bit to fix this (and I do), but this requires manual effort, and changing the text to match the formatting is not quite what I thought Teχ was for, so I wish to have an automatic solution (I could still see places with bad spacing in the PDF output and do the shuffle dance, but I no longer would be *required* to *manually* review *each and every single* PDF built from the source after each change).

Comment: Why are you using `\RequirePackage`? That's not how you conventionally load packages in a document (although it's almost technically the same). Go see this question, does it help? [How to get long \texttt sections to break](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299/4778)

Comment: @Alenanno the person who wrote the house `.sty` file did; if I can improve, do tell. The question doesn’t help, as the `texttt` block should not be broken (i.e. current behaviour is good), but thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, if it can't break, then your only option is to show the link alone in a new line. There aren't any more options than that.

Comment: Would it be possible to show the link in a footnote?

Comment: @Alenanno it’s not a link, it’s inline text (no footnote either). Yes, alone in a new line (or possibly with text following it) would be correct, so why doesn’t Teχ do that? (I understand it’s because the intra-word spacing in the line before the long tt would be too large, but that’s a price I’d be willing to pay.)

Comment: Add `\linebreak` like `...dem Verzeichnis\linebreak`. It will justify the previous line.

Comment: @Alenanno Which part of **automatically** do you not understand? I already wrote this in the question, but I’ll repeat it for you: if I spot these cases in the document, I can take manual action, but I want it to at least not spread content into the page margin automatically.

Comment: Similar: [Pleasing line breaks with extremely long words that must fit on the page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222291/pleasing-line-breaks-with-extremely-long-words-that-must-fit-on-the-page)

Comment: @mirabilos There's no need to be rude with people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @Alenanno by the definition of StackOverflow, you aren’t trying to help me. But sorry if it came across rude.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I could do something with [emergencystretch](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59131/43807)?

Comment: Why are you not using `\url` from the `url` or `hyperref` packages for these strings?

Comment: @AndrewSwann because they’re *not* URLs.

Comment: `\url` is not just for urls.  From the package description: "The com­mand `\url` is a form of ver­ba­tim com­mand that al­lows line­breaks at cer­tain char­ac­ters or com­bi­na­tions of char­ac­ters... The command is intended for email ad­dresses, hy­per­text links, di­rec­to­ries/paths, etc., ..." Using this would allow line breaks within your strings at reasonable points.

Comment: @AndrewSwann you missed the part where I wish to not have any linebreaks in those strings ;-) In some places I have them, but not here.

Comment: Your question doesn't state that.  May be you should update it.

Comment: @AndrewSwann my question states “with texttt”, that is quite explicit in saying I want to fix it for texttt, not switch to url…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/241355/43807) detailling which does what, and what `\sloppy` internally does, I’ve decided to go with the following, for now:

```
% Zu lange Zeilen
\emergencystretch 5em%
```

The value of 5 *em* is probably too large, but it doesn’t seem to hurt so far and judging from the documentation.

Comment: Perfect. Worked like magic.

Comment: does not work for me

Comment: @JFFIGK adjust the value if needed (will look uglier though)

Answer (score 0):

You need to say how to get enough white space to allow the unbreakable string to go to a new line, two possibilities, allow larger inter-word stretch or allow white space at ends of lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[a4paper,includeheadfoot,inner=2.4cm,outer=2cm,top=1.78cm,bottom=1.5cm,twoside,headheight=1.1cm,headsep=0.9cm,foot=1.2cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\RequirePackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}

{\sloppy
Falls Sie von einer VerA.web-Version, die die Konfigurationsdateien
noch nicht in \texttt{/etc/veraweb} ablegt, aktualisieren, müssen Sie
dort zunächst (nur) die gegenüber den in der \texttt{veraweb.war}
ausgelieferten Dateien angepaßten Konfigurationen aus dem Verzeichnis
\texttt{/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/veraweb/OCTOPUS/config\_*.xml}
Ihrer alten Installation hinkopieren.

}

{\raggedright
Falls Sie von einer VerA.web-Version, die die Konfigurationsdateien
noch nicht in \texttt{/etc/veraweb} ablegt, aktualisieren, müssen Sie
dort zunächst (nur) die gegenüber den in der \texttt{veraweb.war}
ausgelieferten Dateien angepaßten Konfigurationen aus dem Verzeichnis
\texttt{/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/veraweb/OCTOPUS/config\_*.xml}
Ihrer alten Installation hinkopieren.

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost good… but this still requires me to add `\sloppy` to the paragraphs manually. Can I set this globally, and is that actually a good idea to do?

Comment: @mirabilos sure you can put it at the start of the document. It's a good idea if that's what you want, a bad idea if only parts of the text have difficult content and need it (you can turn it off with `\fussy` if you do not use a group)

Comment: OK thanks, I’ll play with this later (on a deadline again).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Doesn't `\sloppy` create underfull boxes?

Comment: @Alenanno it depends how you define things, it increases tolerance which means that more stretch is allowed before things are counted as underfull, and it sets emergencystretch which adds extra stretch that is distributed across the paragraph so tex can act as if the lines were not underful even if tolerance would otherwise be exceeded.