# How to set a character as a potential hyphenation point globally ?

Tags: hyphenation

I am generating a LaTeX file, and I got some very long commands containing Windows path, which do not break at line end. For instance, I can have a line like this :

```
This is a \texttt{very\textbackslash{}long\textbackslash{}command\textbackslash{}that\textbackslash{}will\textbackslash{}not\textbackslash{}break\textbackslash{}at\textbackslash{}textbackslash{}the\textbackslash{}end\textbackslash{}of\textbackslash{}the\textbackslash{}line}.
```

Is there any way to set the `\textbackslash{}` (but the question would hold for any character) as a potential hyphenation point ? The generation is automated, so I cannot add a `\-` manually, which I would do normally.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: `\textbackslash` is a macro. Do you actually mean the macro `\textbackslash` or rather `\ `?

Comment: In this case it's a macro yes, but I am looking for a generic solution, for instance it would have been a Linux path, and in this case, I'd like the `/` to be an hyphenation point. So yes, in this case, I mean `\textbackslash` Sorry for being bad at explaining ^^

Comment: Why don't you use the url package?

Comment: Because the above `LaTeX` code is generated via Pandoc, from an HTML source, so I have to work with that :)

Comment: Is the url correctly marked up in the html?

Comment: Perhaps this answer of egreg's might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50777/how-to-emulate-url-hyphenating-without-using-the-url-package/50782#50782

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to coerce the generating program to write, say, `\bslash{}` instead of `\textbackslash`, you can define

```
\newcommand{\bslash}{\textbackslash\penalty\exhyphenpenalty}
```

just like `\slash` is defined (which is the macro you can use for the similar problem with Unix paths).