# `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode - Texmaker

Tags: bibliographies, errors, compiling, urls, texmaker

I use [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) and I keep getting this error:

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in horizontal mode.
```

However I can force compile it using `cmdline` as `pdflatex foo.tex`.

Any idea what the error could be?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{underscore}
\begin{document}
{\large Thesis Advisory Committee}
       random text
\end{document}
```

It says the error is near `{\large }`.

I use this in the BiBTeX file:

```
@misc{ten,
    author = {pable, Chandandeep Singh },
    title = {Completely Fair Scheduler},
    howpublished = "\url{http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/completely-fair-scheduler}",
    year = {2009},
    note = "{Online, accessed 25-01-2013}"
}
```

Comment: as the error says you have a `#` character in text, it can only be used as part of macro definitions.

Comment: I do not have `#` character in text.

Comment: @user2015933 Ok. Please add `\listfiles` as a first line of the MWE you posted, try to compile it in TeXmaker. When the error appears, type `x` there, the compilation will be terminated. Then, add the `.log` file of this compilation to the question. Hopefully it will allow to track the error ;)

Comment: I think this has to do with a faulty `.aux` file from a previous run, since that is read around there. Delete that and recompile.

Comment: I deleted everything `rm Version1.aux Version1.bbl Version1.blg Version1.glo Version1.ist Version1.lof Version1.log Version1.lot Version1.out Version1.synctex.gz Version1.pdf Version1.toc` and made it again

Comment: I reckon it happens after compiling the `citation` file.

Comment: @user2015933 Are you meaning after running BibTeX? There is no citation in the example code.

Comment: No. I kicked all the files off. opened it with texmaker, no issues. compiled the bibtex file, ran it again - issue recurred again.

Comment: @user2015933: What BiBTeX file?

Comment: `latex Version1.tex`
`bibtex Version1`
`latex Version1.tex`
`latex Version1.tex`

This is how I compile it.. and open it with texmaker again. that's when the problem starts.

Comment: @user2015933 your MWE doesn't have a bibtex file but you say you ran bibtex?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15032/url-references-in-bibliography - does lockstep's answer solve the problem?